# Как в Wireshark вместо IP отображать имена хостов

Tags: wireshark

Как в Wireshark вместо IP отображать имена хостов, насколько я знаю есть такая возможность? например чтобы вместо destination ip был хост

Comment: https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/37680/can-wireshark-automatically-resolve-the-ip-address-into-host-names/  оно?

Comment: @nmd да, дай бог тебе здоровья!

Comment: Спасибо! Взаимно!